php-fpm dockerization without nginx inside container
I want to use Nginx outside of my container to proxy requests to the PHP-FPM inside my container. I know the Dockerfile is incomplete, as other libraries are needed.
Dockerfile
FROM php:8.2-fpm

WORKDIR /var/www

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql

# Install Composer
# RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Expose port 9000 to communicate with the web server
EXPOSE 9000

docker-compose
version: '3.8'
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www

NGINX is installed inside the VM
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_page 404 /index.php;
    root /var/www/public;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
    
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        gzip_static on;
    }
}


nginx error log inside the VM

2024/04/13 19:18:48 [emerg] 2975258#2975258: host not found in
upstream "app" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/backend:21 2024/04/13
19:22:42 [emerg] 2993849#2993849: host not found in upstream "app" in
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/backend:21

the part of my files in the VM
/var/www/backend/prep


"host not found" means that nginx can't resolve a host name. "app" in this case is simply unknown to it. Just use "localhost:9000", because that's where you published that service.

Did you add the configuration depends_on to nginx service like this
depends_on:
    - app


I think he meant nginx isn't in docker - so I assume it's running on the host - so localhost:9000 is the way to go

i have been able to solve it i will answer the question

Yup, have a nice day to all guys
